# clarification on ARQC , TC , AAC and Second Card Action Analysis

Tags: transactions, payment, icc, payment-processing, emv

1. How can I know whether to process EMV transaction for go Online, Offline and what are the tags to look into ?
2. What are the tags to look for card response after Online Approval with Issuer Scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Analysis as to proceed as Online/Offline or Decline offline is done by terminal and card. Read about terminal risk management, terminal action analysis, issuer action analysis in detail(TAC-Online, TAC-Denial, TAC-Default, IAC-Online, IAC-Denial, IAC-Default). EMVCo Books 3 will help.
   Based on the cryptogram information data (9F27) terminal comes to know of the cards decision whether it was to go offline, online or decline.
2. 91, 71, 72 and 9F18

Comment: I came to know the same 9F27 for a decision on go-online or offline decline.It helps.